# Determine if SKPaymentTransaction is an auto-renewable transaction

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

I'm implementing auto-renewable subscriptions, where the IAP receipt is being sent up to our server and then validated with Apple's servers (server to server).

I noticed that the auto-renew transactions are still getting added to my devices `SKPaymentQueue`. However I already sent up the receipt data to my server, so I want to skip over these transactions since my server is polling/getting callbacks from Apple's to manage the users subscription status. Is there a way to do that?

Or should I not be skipping these transactions and sending up the receipt data every time I get a new transaction in the queue, even if its just the auto-renew.

Comment: You should not ignore those transactions, otherwise they will build up in the queue.  You need to call `finishTransaction` for them. Whether you send the receipt to the server or not is up to you.

Comment: @Paulw11 Is there anyway to determine if those transactions are just the auto renew ones, vs the initial subscribe transaction?

Comment: Did you happen to find a solution to this? I have exactly the same question/problem.